# On Macos Catlina - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets'

Tags: php, macos

when I check php info php,
I am getting:

`Sockets Support enabled`,

I am unable to make out what this error means and how to fix it.

```
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets' 
(tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sockets 
(dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sockets, 9): image not found),
 /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sockets.so 
(dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sockets.so, 9): image not found))
```

I am using yii2 framework and this error shows up when saving the form which includes image/upload.